# How to get a selected contacts?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new to Android. I have two activities. First activity shows selected contact list from second activity. Second activity shows contact list from database with checkbox. Now I can read a contact list from database and shows at checkbox. Therefore I don't know how to pass selected contacts from first to second activity and how to display selected contact list. Is there any easy way to do it?

Thank you for every advice and guide.

Thanks,
Zeck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you have to get Data from your database 
   then create a CursorAdapter or any Adapter you want and 
   fill it with data and override getView() there. 
   Here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html
   and here http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/
2. Set your adapter into a ListView then 
   implement onclicklistener on this ListView 
   where you will pass the data to Bundle and start a new Activity

[listView onclick goes to a new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852307/listview-onclick-goes-to-a-new-activity)
Here 
http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/passing-data-between-activities-in-android/
and here
http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/17/android---passing-data-between-activities.aspx

There're many other ways how to share the data between activities 
like SharedPreferences or Sqlite database. But it's not the topic for this answer.

---

hope it helps abit

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is someone have same example code like this? I want to learn from geeks.

Comment: @Zeck this site is also awesome if you search right and this one is full of good tutorials http://www.vogella.de/android.html