# Start an Activity from Clicking an Button inside an ListItem

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have a button inside my ListItem that I want to click and launch a new Activity.

In my CustomListAdapter class, I binded the button to an onClickListener but I have no idea how to launch an ActivityforResult from the Activity that contains the ListView.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        PostHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
             holder.btnQuickAdd = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.btnQuickAdd);
        }

        holder.btnQuickAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Launch An Activity

        }
    });
```

Comment: Well show us your code. At least what you have thus far please.

Comment: you can set the onClickListener on your rowView and check it by the listItem (TextView) selected. After that you can call the next activity on corrosponding click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an Solution.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        PostHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
             holder.btnQuickAdd = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.btnQuickAdd);
        }

        holder.btnQuickAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(((MainActivity) v.getContext()), AnotherActivity.class);    
                 ((MainActivity) v.getContext()).startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1002);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First see this Link,

[listView onclick goes to a new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852307/listview-onclick-goes-to-a-new-activity)

You can pass the value by this

```
   Intent in=new Intent(NewChart.this,PieChartView.class);
    in.putExtra("Ref-name", values);//sample in.putExtra("flag",1);
```

Comment: This handle onClick for the whole ListItem. I want to only launch an Activity when you click a specific button inside of a ListItem

Comment: Ok i understand. Within few minutes i will give some suggestions.Wait

Comment: Can you share your coding that you mention the custom list adapter to show the buttons?

Comment: < http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-with-nested.html > try this link. I think it's looks might be better for you. Or else share your list adapter code ,i want to see what you are trying so far.